# PostMapping Id handling

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I think my question is easy, but i do not find a solution.

I have a HTML file where i create two buttons

```
<button id="saveEmployee" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
<button id="deleteEmployee" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Delete</button>
```

and i have two PostMapping in my controller class

```
    @PostMapping
public String saveButton(Employee employee) {
    Employee saved = employeeRepository.save(employee);

    return "redirect:/employee/" + saved.getEmployeeId() + "/view";
}

@PostMapping
public String deleteButton(Employee employee) {
    employeeRepository.deleteByEmployeeId(employee.getEmployeeId());

    return "redirect:/employee/create";
}
```

now i want to handle the correct PostMapping by the both id "saveEmployee" and "deleteEmloyee".

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by add a parameter to check whether user clicks delete or save.

for example

In your buttons add name and value attribute

```
<button id="saveEmployee" name="btn" value="Save" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
<button id="deleteEmployee" name="btn" value="Delete" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Delete</button>
```

And in your controller use @RequestMapping instead.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someurl", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleSaveDelete(@RequestParam("employee") Employee employee, @RequestParam("btn") String button){
  if("Save".equals(button)) {
    // Save
  }else if("Delete".equals(button)){
   // Delete
  }

  return "redirect:/";
}
```

Hope it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this page is helpfully to you https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

One approach could look like:

```
<form action="/save/" method="post">    
    <button id="saveEmployee" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>

<form action="/delete/" method="post">    
    <button id="deleteEmployee" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Delete</button>
</form>
```

and:

```
    @PostMapping("/save/")
public String saveButton(Employee employee) {
    Employee saved = employeeRepository.save(employee);

    return "redirect:/employee/" + saved.getEmployeeId() + "/view";
}

@PostMapping("/delete/")
public String deleteButton(Employee employee) {
    employeeRepository.deleteByEmployeeId(employee.getEmployeeId());

    return "redirect:/employee/create";
}
```